# Visual Studio 2015 publishing include css files when using sass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, webdeploy, web-essentials, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 preview and compiling SASS files with Grunt.
And locally everything works great.

But when it comes to publishing, there are some differences:

- In Visual Studio 2013 .scss files were compiled into .css files by Visual Studio (or Web Essentials)
- When compiled, .css files were added to project as subfiles for .scss files
- .css files were published with everything else

Now with Visual Studio 2015 version, .scss files are not compiled anymore and we have to configure Grunt for that, which I think is just great, because of various things! Except this:

- When Grunt compiles .scss files to .css files, it is happening outside of Visual Studio
- Files are created on the disk, but they are not included into project automatically
- When publishing, .css files are ignored, because they are not a part of project

Therefore, I have two questions:

- How can I configure Visual Studio to add those files as subfiles for .scss files (prefered)
- If that is not really possible (at least for now), how can I get Visual Studio publishing tool to include the in publishing package?

Comment: AFAIK, when you include any file on the project structure it should automatically be added to the project. If the file is inside the wwwroot it will also be published. Are you saying that this is **not** happening ?

Comment: It is adding .scss files, but *not* adding the generated .css files.

Comment: What folder are css getting generated?

Comment: .css files are generated right besides the .sass files

Comment: I think you're talking about Website project. But in my case it is Web Application Project (WAP) and not Website, therefore there's no wwwroot folder. I am using Cloud Service and there is no option for Web Role to be Website, only WAP.

Comment: Grunt gulp are for "vnext" (mvc6) and they have a wwwroot. I think you are mixing project type and capabilities.

Comment: Grunt and Gulp are not for vNext or any other project type specifically. They are just tools. I user them, because there is no .sass files compilation in VS 2015 anymore. And as I said, I am happy with them. The only problem is including files generated by them have to be done manually. I thought maybe someone else will know how to automate that.

Comment: As of right now (preview version) the watch on project changes is implemented on vnext projects afaik.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually add the generated .css files to your project, they will be included in the publish.  When Grunt updates them, Visual Studio will see the updated file.